# A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value. This is usually caused by not using RequestContext

Tags: django, django-forms, print, jspdf, report

Estoy intentando crear un pdf desde un html que contiene dos formularios. En la vista trato de llamar a los formularios y asimismo enviar el id para que me llene los formularios con los datos y que así se imprima el pdf con los datos llenos, pero me da ese error.

> UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.

**Urls.py**

```
path('mostrar/<int:id>', views.ficha, name='ficha'),
```

**Views.py**

```
def ficha(request, id=None):
reg = get_object_or_404(Registro, pk=id) if id else None
form = RegistroForm(instance=reg)
form2 = InfoEquipoForm(instance=reg.marca)
template = get_template('registro/ficha.html')
ctx = {
    'form': form,
    'form2':form2,
    'id':id,
}
html = template.render(ctx)
pdf = HTML(string=html).write_pdf(target="asig.pdf")
return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

**ficha.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

{% block titulo %}
Reportes
{% endblock %}

{% block contenido %}

```
<div class="container-fluid px-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2"></div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <form class="row g-4" action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row g-4">
                        <h2 class="text-center">Datos del Usuario</h2> <hr class="text-center mb-4">
                        
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                                <div class="mb-2" disabled>Usuario</div>
                                {{ form.asignacion }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                                <div class="mb-2">Código de empleado</div>
                                {{ form.codEmp }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                                <div class="mb-2">Gerencia</div>
                                {{ form.gerencia }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                                <div class="mb-2">Fecha</div>
                                {{ form.fecha }}
                            </div>
                        
                </div>
                <div class="row g-4">
                        <h2 class="text-center">Datos del Equipo</h2> <hr class="text-center mb-4">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-2">Equipo</div>
                            {{ form.equipo }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-2">Computadora</div>
                            {{ form.marca }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-1">Serie</div>
                            {{ form2.serie }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-1">Modelo</div>
                            {{ form2.modelo }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-1">Procesador</div>
                            {{ form2.procesador }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-1">Sistema Operativo</div>
                            {{ form2.sistema }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-1">Ram 1</div>
                            {{ form2.ram1 }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-1">Ram 2</div>
                            {{ form2.ram2 }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-1">Disco</div>
                            {{ form2.disco }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-1">Máscara de red</div>
                            {{ form2.mac }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 date">
                            <div class="mb-2">Proceso</div>
                            {{ form.proceso }}
                        </div>
                </div>  
                
                <div class="row g-5">
                    <div class="col-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><hr>
                            <div class="mb-2 text-center"><strong>Firma Gerencia</strong></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><hr>
                            <div class="mb-2 text-center"><strong>Firma Usuario</strong></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1"></div>
                    
                </div>
                
            </form> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-2"></div>
                          
    </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: Para una correcta identación de tu código en la pregunta, ponlo entre triples tildes graves (```).

Comment: debes agregar `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` a tu render!

Comment: estuve probando y me daba otro error, no se si estoy colocando mal el render, me muestras como lo pondrías porfa?